# Html.DropDownListFor doesn't select the right object

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdown, html.dropdownlistfor

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ObjectId, 
     Model.SelectListItems, 
     "Default", 
     new { @id = "DropDown" })
```

Controller

```
TheViewModel model = ((TheViewModel )Session[nameof(TheViewModel )]);
if (model == null)
{
    // fill model with data
}
return View(model);
```

I load the viewmodel from the session and want now to set the selected value by the id (from the model), but it doesn't work on this way.
But in the post method I get the right information in my model and when i load the data from the session is also everything set.

Please notice that I don't want to use viewbag

Both vars are set in the controller. 
ObjectId is an int

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to set the value of `ObjectId` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view

Comment: can you provide code of action and view?

Comment: Simply use  `var model = new ViewModel(); model.ObjectId = "DefaultSelectedValue"` then `return View(model);` on `HttpGet` controller action method.

Comment: the value of objectId is null

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto objectId is a int, i can't set it with a string

Comment: @Thismanagain please post your action code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Testy20161006.Models
{
    public class AnItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }


    public class TheViewModel
    {
        public TheViewModel()
        {
            items.Add(new AnItem { Id = 1, Name = "dh1" });
            items.Add(new AnItem { Id = 2, Name = "dh2" });
            items.Add(new AnItem { Id = 3, Name = "dh3" });
        }

        public string SelectedValue { get; set; }

        public List<AnItem> items = new List<AnItem>();

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items
        {
            get { return new SelectList(items, "Id", "Name"); }
        }
        public string RequiredValidationMessage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index26(TheViewModel m)
    {
        var selectedText = m.SelectedValue;
        return View(m);
    }

    public ActionResult Index26()
    {
        TheViewModel m = new TheViewModel();
        return View(m);
    }
```

View:

```
@model  Testy20161006.Models.TheViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index26</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedValue)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedValue,
        new SelectList(Model.Items, "Value", "Text"))

            <input type="submit" value="Get Value of dropdown" />
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped :)